# Phantom update model with Optional values

Tags: scala, phantom-dsl

I have an update method on my model which takes a class with option types, and I want to construct an update statement which includes a dynamic SET depending on which fields have values.  Using Phanton-dsl 1.5 I had something like so;

```
import com.websudos.phantom.query.{ AssignmentsQuery => AQ }

override def updateModel(m: Upd)(implicit ec: EC): Future[Unit] = {
    if (m.isEmpty) return Future.successful(())
    val upd = update
    upd.where(_.user_id eqs m.user_id)
    val mod: AQ[CTable, Val] = new AQ(this, upd.qb.`with`())
    for (first_name <- m.first_name) mod.and(_.first_name setTo first_name)
    for (last_name <- m.last_name) mod.and(_.last_name setTo last_name)
    mod.future.map(_ => ())
}
```

Now I'm trying to move to the latest release of Phantom-dsl (1.27) and I'm having trouble with doing the equivalent using just the dsl.  Since any field may be None, constructing the first modify() then proceeding that with any number of and(), is proving difficult.

Any suggestions on how to deal with this would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible using `setIfDefined` and you don't need to wrap anything.

```
db.table.update.where(_.bla eqs bla)
  .modify(_.x setIfDefined None)
  .and(_.y setIfDefined Some("text")
```

This will basically ignore all the things that are `None` and it will force them to not show in the query.

Comment: I'm getting this error when I try 'setIfDefined'   `value setIfDefined is not a member of object x$9.first_name
[error]       .modify(_.first_name setIfDefined first_name)`

Comment: What version of phantom are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 1.27.0

Comment: You need 1.28.14 for that operator to be available

Comment: even after moving to 1.28.14 I'm still getting that error, here is where my build is getting the jar `[info] downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/websudos/phantom-dsl_2.11/1.28.14/phantom-dsl_2.11-1.28.14.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] com.websudos#phantom-dsl_2.11;1.28.14!phantom-dsl_2.11.jar (575ms)`

Comment: @DavidInglis Try refreshing SBT or similar, I've double checked and this is definitely the version where the operator was introduced. Look here: https://github.com/outworkers/phantom/commit/91579325dd24766b905161236419d724fe2496b3

Comment: So, I think my problem if that the Columns need to be defined as Optional[Type]Column, where I have them defined as static types. As I change this the error goes away.  Thanks

Comment: @DavidInglis I think that may be a current limitation, we will remove it in the next release. In theory you should be able to use `setIfDefined` on non `Optional` columns.

Comment: @flavian setIfDefined for every type would be welcome. Can you indicate when this ends up in a release or link to a JIRA?